# Please help me to select the best form composition for this backyard design

Tags: landscaping, design

Below you have the existing areas designated as marked. 
Just below the access path to the left side I intend to install an outdoor sofa, parallel to the fence (it can now be seen in the 3Ds). The left side threes belong to my neighbor.
The green rectangle to left bottom side is a vegetable garden

**Update as requested:**
**-NNW is at the top of the page, vertical axe of the schematic diagrams**
-no drainage issues
-vegetable garden positioned there because it is the least visible and close to the shed where the tools are. Shed is there ..because that is the best area for it :-)
-exterior brick veneer
-no pets
-USDA zone: 6a (Toronto)
-prefer perenials and evergreen (but not for trees)
-the trees in my design: Japanese Maple (Emperor wolf), Hybrid Dogwood, and again a green leaf Japanese maple.
-fence segment parallel with the garden will be a perennial flowering vine (Trumpets Vine or climbing rose)
-privacy was addressed by the below showed placement of the trees Basicall I need privacy in the patio area.
-I do not insist to have a lot of lawn
-watering will be done with an irrigation system
-no previous landscaping experience (if you check the homereno diy section of stackexchange you will see my work on the patio and some pictures)
- I do not intend to post more pictures
-no other areas other that what is suggested. 
-the BBQ is next to the wall parallel with the patio table (so that is the kitchen for now)

**I basically need help with a theme not with the detailed design, something like what is encircled in green belowk:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zlzah.png ☚ direct link to full size picture

[image]

**-NNW is at the top of the page, vertical axe of the below diagram**

[image]

And here is the best idea I could come up with. A rectangular theme where 1,2,3,4 have the same size. I must admit that it will be a challenge for me to create these areas (1,2,3) either with plants or some hardscaping materials

What would you change or how would you do it? What do you consider that I should change?

**-NNW is at the top of the page, vertical axe of the below diagram**

[image]
 And here is a 3D

[image]

Here I added the sofa. That in the 3D is not exactly the style that I want. It will be more like this:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I could also center the sofa on the longitudinal axe of the biggest area of the backyard as below but that will squize the dwarf tree that would be planted in the that corner behind the sofa, corner that I want to be a second focal point (lights might be installed there) This will be a focal point for the viewer from the deck as well. (dwarf japanese maple of dwarf pine or strong color shrub)

[image]

View from the kitchen with a view that I am trying to block. Basically my neighbor and myself see each other from the kitchen or deck. There was a tree there but the former owner cut it for unknown reasons.

[image]

I have also added the windows in the 3D so you can have an idea what the viewer sees from the house

[image]

**Update: How about this idea:**

[image]

Comment: Good use of your software but there are a few questions we have to know; where is NORTH, which trees on the left are the neighbors?  I am assuming on our right as we are looking at your plan. What is your drainage, any issues with standing water you've noticed?  Do you have pets, why your location for a vegetable garden?  What material is your home exterior?  What plants are existing?  What do you imagine your landscape to look like, how will you be using your landscape, have you thought about different types of out door uses?  How much lawn do you need/want?  Are you on well water/city water?

Comment: Also send actual pictures, more information on your location, USDA zone, neighbors (do you need privacy or a neighborly gate).  Do you have any preferences with plant material, have you ever done a landscape for a previous home.  Are you going to do the work yourself or will you contract the work?  This should generate even more questions that require answers and more thought.  Landscaping is not an inexpensive venture, if done correctly however will add more value to your home than a new kitchen or bathroom!!  How much of a gardener are you?

Comment: I taught L.S. Graphics and Design...whoohoo!  Hand drawn not computer drawn.  Just an 'old' style I could never change to computer, not this late in the game.  Any way, you need to define what you mean by 'theme'.  The ONLY theme is 'MiniMe's Outdoor Spaces'...grins.  Can't believe you answered so quickly!!  I'll get back tomorrow...at worse day after.  Do you have pictures of landscapes that look great to you enough to save?  Good job!

Comment: Yeah I guess my second choice for a profession would have been architect or landscape designer, I do like it, I am a visual person ...
I like the minimalist style. Japanese garden would be ideal but considering some of the things are already around us and a limited supply of money I thing that bringing in rocks and more stone like landscaping material is out of question. Small rocks for my sedums and hen and chickes and any other hardy succulents that I can buy will be>
possible. 

Rock garden would be my second choice...
Modern style is the last...

Comment: There should be a directional arrow, or compass, on your drawing to indicate North as a minimum - the direction your garden faces dictates possible micro climate, wind exposure and sunlight, so its crucial. If its there somewhere, I'm not seeing it...

Comment: I indicated at the top of each diagram that NNW is at the top of the picture.

Comment: do a food forest with animals, and save on the food bill

Comment: I would rather make this world better avoiding a stupid caustic person

Comment: Major grins...hey MiniMe!  Just got back and checked in.  Sorry so late.  Great fun with this computerized stuff.  Not bad...helps if one can't actually be on site.  One thing I can say until tomorrow, is keep your trees and plants the same to allow a specimen or focal point to work.  No good doing one of this and one of that.  You get tons more punch to have masses of plants.  Humans feel comfy only with 3 different stimuli. Some more some people less.  Think massing.  If every plant is a focal point it will feel very awkward.  Oh, should not be able to see all from the home.  Tomorrow...

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I was aware of that rule but I need those three trees there ..not sure if it is a good idea to have three japanese maple of the same sort there or three dogwoods ...what other options do I have?

Comment: If you are going to have three trees keep them the same.  Your design almost screams for an allee, very formal use of trees all the same to highlight your rectangular design.  Hey, I LOVE this rectangular 90 degree angles, pavers type of design.  Again, try to HIDE the expanse of your yard.  Another detail is sadly buildings and code.  There is a percentage of NON permeable landscape you are allowed.  Even using rocks, gravel is a big reduction of that percentage, decks OVER the soil, reduce that percentage.  Go check out the rules right now before you go any further...with your city/county!

Comment: I love that couch, bucko!! I can help with the permeable surfaces...find out what the rules are...

Comment: I just added one more crazy idea :-) see at the bottom of the initial message

Comment: Yes!!  I love that room!  Excellent.  I have to know what the buildings and code for your city have determined how much of your property needs to be permeable...a percentage! ??  Sure you could try to bag or ignore the rules and I get it...how well do you know your neighbors??   Sometimes playing the design game and staying within the rules will make an even better design.  If the 'rules' dictate a percentage above what you've got going (pretty much zero percent) there are LOTS of ways to work within those rules to increase the permeability of your lot.  Keep sending your ideas generated...

Comment: Any idea on how to arrange the trees? I have done a couple of simulations and that corner to the bottom right side of the last picture does not get a lot of sun especially if the the only tree that you see on the back side of the corner. I don't think that the permeability will be a problem. If I have to build a base for the furniture I would rather do it with some concrete squares placed just under the legs for the sofas and table. The pergola would have its own concrete base for each post

Comment: I am not aware of any limitations in Toronto in regards to lot permeability. However my front yard is much twice bigger than the back yard

Comment: What would be a recommended site for that pergola??